# How to return list from linq query using viewmodels

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have classes like this

```
public class class1
    {
        public int class1id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    public class class2
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int class1id { get; set; }
        public string from { get; set; }
        public string to { get; set; }
    }

    public class viewmodel
    {
        public class2 deletedocument { get; set; }
        public IList<class2> deletelist { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i want to return a list with name,from,to properties. Here name from class1 and class1id is foreign key(class1). How can i do this? Do i need to change my viemodel?

Comment: You view model needs to contain the 3 properties you want (`name`, `from` and `to`)

Comment: yes. How can i put 3 properties in viewmodel? Directly i can put or i need to convert all properties to list? Finally i want to bind list to object of viewmodel and then i want to pass it to view. Is it possible?

Comment: No, they should not be lists, just `public string name { get; set; }` etc (and then you create a collection of your view model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Model**

What you can do is to make a `Model` having those three properties:

```
public class MyModel {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

And then in your `Razor` `View`, you declare an `IEnumerable<MyModel>` as your `Model`

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.MyModel>
```

**Controller**

And in your `Controller` you query from your two other queries, creating `IEnumerable<MyModel>` in the process and return it

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    var models = from a in blabla //query what you want here, generate IEnumerable<MyModel>
                 join b in blabla2 on a.class1id equals b.class1id
                 select new MyModel{ name = a.name, from = b.from, to = c.to}
    return View(models);
}
```

Comment: Actually i have some data to post something like this @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.deletelist.from and i am displaying something like this  foreach (var item in Model.deletelist) {  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)} so i dont want @model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.MyModel>

Comment: @Niranjan if you do not need `deletelist` to be in your model, you could put that to `ViewBag` to avoid confusion. But if you really need that, then you need to change your `Controller` `Index` `Action` like what I show to have your `viewmodel` instance who have both the `IEnumerable<MyModel>` and the `deletelist` so you can use the `deletelist` as you already did. But I would prefer not to mix delete list with my `MyModel`

Comment: This seems to be working. But how can post data to db and display data in same view? I should change my @Html.TextBoxFor and Html.DisplayFor is it?

Comment: @Niranjan yes, it is possible to have both post and get in the same `View`. you need decorator `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` in your controller to do that to say which want will be Post and which one will be Get, but it is possible

Comment: everything fine but i am sending model to the view of type viewmodel model. so i want to copy  var models to viewmodel model. Is it possible?

Comment: @Niranjan yes, what you can do is to have your `viewmodel` having something like, let say `IEnumerable<MyModel>` as one of its properties. Then you just need to attach your query result in the controller to that property. :)

Comment: public IEnumerable<viewmodel> ienmodel { get; set; } Something like this? Sir How to attach query result?

Comment: @Niranjan No no, it should be `IEnumerable<MyModel> ienmodel` (use `MyModel` to distinguish it with `viewmodel`) and the `MyModel` is as what I have given as example, queried as what I have shown. Then in your `Controller` Action like what I have shown, you could do something like `vmodel.ienmodel = models` where `models` is like what I have shown in my example.

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[c3card.Dal.EDModel.MyViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'c3card.Dal.EDModel.ViewModel'. This error appears

Comment: Al worked fine now. But returning 0 rows but data is there.

Comment: @Niranjan then it might be the query problem. Again, this you may check in your side since you will know better.